How to decode JWT token in Android without libraries?
How to decode JWT token in Android without libraries?
let's take this JWT token for example:
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
how to get "name" from the token?

See also https://www.baeldung.com/java-jwt-token-decode#decoding-a-jwt
